# 2 factor authentication in salesforce using twilio totp not working correctly

Tags: visual-workflow, sms, twilio

i am trying to trigger otp for 2 factor authentication as per the following documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_3p_sms_2fa_login_flow.htm

What is happening is that. the text box is coming up in which i can enter the otp. But on clicking then it is not validating the otp and it is repeatedly sending me the otp.

Please find attached screen shot of the entire flow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O4Pt.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5. In Step-9, a field called Code is created, which has the default value of {!Code} (created in Step-3). It will have a corresponding Unique Name, which should[image] be used for Value of decision screen (Step-10).